# Trying to send Triggered Email via getting error

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

New to using the ExactTarget API.   I am using this example.   http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/send_triggeredsend_email/.   Trying to send a test email using an existing triggered send.   With this example, I see Error for status.    I am able to use the soap client with my login and do basic subscribe queries.    Sending an email, I can't get to work.    Please advise thanks.

```
        // Create the SOAP Client (and pass in the endpoint and the binding)
        SoapClient client = new SoapClient();

        // Set the username and password
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "#USERNAME#";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "#PASSWORD#";

        TriggeredSendDefinition definition = new TriggeredSendDefinition();
        definition.CustomerKey = "#TRIGGERED_SEND_EXTERNAL_ID#";

        ClientID clientID = new ClientID();
        clientID.PartnerClientKey = "#MID_FOR_BUSINESS_UNIT#"; //this is sub-accounts partner-key
        //Tell system to create this definition in Sub-account
        definition.Client = clientID;

        //subscriber to whom email will be sent
        Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();
        subscriber.EmailAddress = "test@test.com";
        subscriber.SubscriberKey = "test@test.com";

        TriggeredSend send = new TriggeredSend();
        send.TriggeredSendDefinition = definition;

        //If passing Full HTML_Body, pass value to HTML__Body (This attribute should exist in account)
        com.exacttarget.Attribute attribute1 = new com.exacttarget.Attribute();
        attribute1.Name = "RFR_FirstName";
        attribute1.Value = "FirstName";
        subscriber.Attributes = new com.exacttarget.Attribute[] { attribute1 }; //set attribute value and assign that to subscriber


        send.Subscribers = new Subscriber[] { subscriber }; //set subscriber to Triggered send

        APIObject[] sends = { send };
        String requestId = null;
        String overAllStatus = null;
        CreateOptions test = new CreateOptions();
        //If you want to send email Asynchronous, Business Rule should be enabled.
        test.RequestType = RequestType.Asynchronous;
        CreateResult[] results = client.Create(new CreateOptions(), sends, out requestId, out overAllStatus);
        Response.Write("Status ::: " + overAllStatus);
```

Comment: Can you print out the details from the results  variable defined in the 2nd line from the bottom of your example?  That is where you would find details about why the request resulted in an error.